# Insert rows into a Pandas DataFrame where rows are missing based on previous row values

Tags: pandas, rows, missing-data

I am new to Python and this is my first post, so I apologize for any ambiguous phrasing.

I have a table with column A that increments from 1 to 5 for several iterations. I'd like to scan column A and where this pattern doesn't match insert the correct number for A,  copy column C and leave a missing value for column B.

Just inserting a row with missing values at the correct place would be helpful.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

You can [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by  [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and then fill missing values in column `C` by [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
df['G'] = (df.A.diff().fillna(-1) < 1).cumsum()
df.set_index(['G','A'], inplace=True)
print (df)
       B    C
G A          
1 1    1  Feb
  2    8  Feb
  4   64  Feb
  5  125  Feb
2 1    0  Feb
  3    6  Feb
  4   16  Feb
  5   31  Feb
3 1   -3  Feb
  3    4  Feb
  4   18  Feb
  5   29  Feb
```

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.get_level_values('G').unique(), 
                                  np.arange(1,6)], names=('G','A'))

df = df.reindex(mux)
df.C = df.C.ffill()

df = df.reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)
    A      B    C
0   1    1.0  Feb
1   2    8.0  Feb
2   3    NaN  Feb
3   4   64.0  Feb
4   5  125.0  Feb
5   1    0.0  Feb
6   2    NaN  Feb
7   3    6.0  Feb
8   4   16.0  Feb
9   5   31.0  Feb
10  1   -3.0  Feb
11  2    NaN  Feb
12  3    4.0  Feb
13  4   18.0  Feb
14  5   29.0  Feb
```

Comment: @Dickster - Thank you :)